# PhantomJs installation

Tags: javascript, windows, path, phantomjs

I'm new with phantomJS , I'v installed it and saved the file in this path C:\bin\Phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows and added this to the windows PATH.
in their manual it says to create a JS file and write the following and save it as hello.js:

console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();

then open the command line and type :
phantomjs hello.js

I keep getting an error that says "parse error".

and when entering the file phantomjs  and it becomes "phantomjs> " and i write hello.js i get another error " cannot find variable : hello "

How can i access the hello file ?

thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/e4f83167-5774-4241-b406-f586e9e51a2d/f53d8b1eab1ec5e6f7d4eb4810230f02

Comment: This is for the Windows version, not the Mac version. There may be an issue with the user's PATH. Can we see a screenshot of your command window?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8w9UQ.png

Comment: I added a screen shot of the current status , thanks

Comment: To use Phantom commandline, you should type commands directly: phantomjs> console.log('Hello, world!'); phantom.exit(); it is invalid to use phantomjs> hello.js

Answer (score 0):

The basic scenario would be to place your JS file in the same folder as phantomjs.exe

1. Navigate to the folder with phantomjs.exe and your js file
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Right click</kbd> and select 'Open command window here'
3. Enter: `phantomjs <fileName>.js`

If this works you can expand the example from there with your path vars. Run this example to make sure that everything is set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

Also when you just type phantomjs, you are entering its console where you can execute javascript code. So when you type in hello.js there, it's trying to interpret it as a javascript code and hello is not defined.